# How do I set a content entity field as required?

Tags: 8, entities

How do I make a field in a content entity required in Drupal 8?

I tried [`FieldConfigInterface::setRequired()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Field!FieldConfigInterface.php/function/FieldConfigInterface%3A%3AsetRequired/8.2.x), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The field is an entity reference dropdown, if that helps

Comment: it should work, did you reinstall the module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the ->setRequired(TRUE) option on the field. IE

```
$fields['source_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Thingy'))
      ->setDescription(t('Pick a thingy'))
      ->setSetting('target_type','thingy')
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'options_select',
        'weight' => 5,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

You will also need to uninstall and then reinstall your module to have the change reflected in the database before this will work.

Comment: Won't an entity schema update also work?

Comment: Quite possibly! Are you talking about this? https://www.drupal.org/node/2535476

Comment: I think that's doing it manually. It should be automagic when running `drush entup`. I think this is the relevant code for Sql content entities - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Sql!SqlContentEntityStorage.php/function/SqlContentEntityStorage%3A%3AonEntityTypeUpdate/8.2.x

Answer (score 3):

If you have an existing field that is optional and you want to make it required, use code similar to the following, in example.install. (Replace *example* with the machine name of the module you created.)

```php
/**
 * Make the "bar" field required.
 */
function example_update_8101(&$sandbox) {
  $entityType = 'foo';
  $fieldName = 'bar';
  $manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $field = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition($fieldName, $entityType);
  $field->setRequired(TRUE);
  $manager->updateFieldStorageDefinition($field);
}
```

This allows you to update a base field definition in Drupal 8. In this example, it's for a custom content entity type **foo** and its **bar** field.

Don't forget to update your `baseFieldDefinitions()` implementation in your entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change it programmatically then use:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'entitytype_id' && isset($fields['body'])) {
    $fields['body']->setRequired(TRUE);
  }
}
```