# Update FieldItemBase database schema

Tags: 8

I need to update a default value of column

```
/**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
  return [
    'columns' => [
      'status' => [
        'description' => 'Whether reactions are allowed on this entity: 0 = no, 1 = closed (read only), 2 = open (read/write).',
        'type' => 'int',
        'default' => 0, // <-- HERE
      ],
    ],
    'indexes' => [],
    'foreign keys' => [],
  ];
}
```

When I changed from 0 to 2 I get error on status report page about "field definitions mismatch"

There are a lot of questions about adding and removing columns. [Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255495/add-column-to-custom-field-schema/295485) for example, but I don't understand how to update schema PROGRAMMATICALLY without adding or removing column

Comment: This is a [better example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/294376/47547), you need only to replace setRequired() with setDefaultValue().

Comment: What "entity type" should I use for FieldItemBase?

Comment: \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldMapByFieldType($field_type)

Comment: I found update field code here https://gist.github.com/JPustkuchen/ce53d40303a51ca5f17ce7f48c363b9b